# Set the button at the very bottom of the layout - Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a table layout in which i have declared a button statically in the XML file. I add rows dynamically in the program. I want the button to be set at the very end of the table layout.
I tried doing that using android:layout_gravity="bottom" but that is not helping.

Any solutions ?

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/table"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: ScrollView. I dont think it should matter. But still.

Comment: can you post your xml file. if scroll view it must containg some layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly it will work for you but what you can do is to remove your button by using remove and then add it at run time after adding all your elements.

Example:

```
    TableLayout tv = (TableLayout ) findViewbyId(R.id.table_layout_id);
    Button button = (Button) findviewbytid(R.id.button_id);
```

May be you need layout param of your button so you can get it easily.

```
    LayoutParams lp = button.getLayoutParams();
```

remove your button from layout.

```
    tv.removeView(button);
```

ADD ALL YOUR VIEW AT RUNTIME.

Add your button again.

```
     tv.addView(button, lp);
```

I havnt tried this code but I think it should work. In some of the cases you don't need layout params so you can ignore it too.

Comment: I dont think I can use RemoveView on TableLayout

Comment: I have just check that function is there to remove views from table.

Comment: If you will be having a complete tablerow in your table layout then you can fetch it completely and remove it from your table. After that you can add it whenever you want. In your case it will be at the end.

Comment: One more thing I have just noticed is that you have set your gravity in button I think you should set it in your table layout.

Comment: Which worked My code or gravity. If my code is working then mark it so that it will be helpful for others...

Comment: Quick clarification. When I use gravity, the button should be placed in the bottom most part of its parent container. Then why doesn't it work well ?

Comment: Yes you are true but gravity controls parent growth. your parent will grow according to gravity but placement of view will be according to the way in which you have added.

Comment: Suppose you have set your gravity in your parent layout as right so all child will stick to right but their position will be in same sequence in which you have added.

Comment: Actually i am also new to android so I don't know what I have explained is exactly correct but I know that only. :)

Comment: I will be better if you mark answer otherwise it will remain in unanswered list and people waste their time to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to reorder the children of a `ViewGroup` without removing all children and readding them in the appropriate order. If a `ListView` will suffice in lieu of a `TableLayout`, it has a `addFooterView()` method which would achieve what you're after.

Comment: I have TableRows which I add to TableLayout. How should I add them in ListView ? Because I tried using ListView but it didn't work.

Comment: If you are having TableRows which you have created dynamically then you can create custom adapter and pass your table row in your custom adapter. There you can set your tablerows in "getView" method.

Comment: If you have created your TableRows in xml file then you can easily inflate your row in "getView" method in custom adapter and then set your tablerows in listview.

Answer (score 0):

put button outside the table and scroll-view......
i mean below the scroll-view